# Torch parallelize tasks for multiple GPUs

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, torch, torchvision

I have two GPU cards and I have torch model which is currently running on one card. I try to
evaluate large task set with both of these cards. `DataParallel` unfortunately does not work with this type of model (`torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn`).

Pseudocode would be

```py
with GPUProcessPool() as p:
    p.starmap(torch_task_function, iterable=[index, task for index, task_path in enumerate(paths)])
```

where the `GPUProcessPool()` would contain a prosess with params for `GPU0` and a process for params `GPU1`. What is the best method to split these task to both GPUs?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of model? maybe add code?

Comment: The model used is `torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn`. I fail to see how any more code would be relevant to this question.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/1659). They suggest using `nn.DistributedDataParallel`, and mentioned it supports all types of models including Faster R-CNN.

Comment: That is precisely what is asked here.